# Linux: journalctl

Tags: linux, logging, lines

I would like to view only log messages created within a specified time range (08:00 - 11:00) for ALL days.

If I use:

```
journalctl --since 08:00 --until 11:00
```

It displays logs from current day only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - where is your journalctl log file? Default journalctl collect logs since the launch of the system.

By default, the log file is in **/var/log/journal**. If this dir isn't exist set **Storage=persistent** in **/etc/systemd/journald.conf** and run **systemctl restart systemd-journald**.

And when journalctl saves all messages/events on all the days or when the system collects logs from a few days of the save settings day You can draw some interesting informations from journalctl in this way:

```
# Define year
year="2016"

# Defines the month in which you want to search
months=(08 09 10)

for i in "${months[@]}" ; do

   # To set a range of days: 14 - 20
   for j in `seq 14 20` ; do
      journalctl --since "${year}-${i}-${j} 08:00:00" --until "${year}-${i}-${j} 11:00:00" >> /tmp/journal.${year}-${i}-${j}.log
   done

done
```

If you want to check days from 1 to 9 will probably need to add a mechanism for adding 0 (01, 02, 03, ..., 09).

This is an example so you have to adjust it to your needs.